# how to compare date and time

Tags: c#, datetime

I am developing an application called reminder using C# - visual studio 2010 . My Application reminds every event entered. Solution bellow works properly but I need to express this just using "datetimepicker" (calendar for date selection is not used)

```
MyRemindTime =dlg.MymonthCalendar.SelectionStart.AddHours(dlg.MyTimePicker.Value.Hour).AddMinutes(dlg.MyTimePicker.Value.Minute).AddSeconds(dlg.MyTimePicker.Value.Second);
timer1.Enabled = true;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyRemindTime.CompareTo (DateTime.Now)<0)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Alarm");
         }
     }
```

Could you please help me how to properly express MyRemindTime? I need to compare current date and time with datetimepicker. Time and datum has to be compared.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the selected date/time as :

```
DateTime reminderTime = myDateTimePicker.Value;
```

And compare with the current time:

```
if(reminderTime < Datetime.Now) 
     //reminder time has passed
```

Comment: No this doesnot works for me. When I use this code - reminder message has observed after few second not in reminder time.

       public partial class qual_template : Form
    {
          
        private DateTime theDay;

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime theDay = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    MessageBox.Show("data saved");
    timer1.Enabled = true;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (theDay < DateTime.Now)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show ("Reminder: " + textBox14.Text);

Comment: that is probably because you run the timer every a few seconds. Try running the timer more often (say every 500 ms).

Comment: I have try this but this is practicly the same. Few seconds after timer enable it show reminder no matter when was reminder set. Does this code realy compare also time with minutes and seconds? Doesnot compare this just datum? Is my expression DateTime theDay ok in public partial class?

Comment: Well where could be a problem? I have declared DateTime the Day. Timer is disabled when application starts. When user select date and time in datetimepicker and click on the save button it has enable timer1. This should verify datetimenow with datetimepicker and show message box. I dont see where the problem could be ... :-(

Comment: SOLUTION :-) :
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            MyRemindTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("saved");
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if (MyRemindTime.CompareTo (DateTime.Now)<0)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Alarm");